# Moving back button to app bar

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I'm currently writing a Windows Store App (XAML/C#). I'm trying to move the back button into the top app bar.

I've tried moving the code for the back button (default code from the BasicPage template) into a AppBar. However, it doesn't bring me back to the previous page when I click it.

This is the code which I moved into the app bar:

```
<Button x:Name="backButton"
  Margin="39,59,39,0"
  Command="{Binding NavigationHelper.GoBackCommand, ElementName=pageRoot}"
  Style="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle}"
  VerticalAlignment="Top"
  AutomationProperties.Name="Back"
  AutomationProperties.AutomationId="BackButton"
  AutomationProperties.ItemType="Navigation Button"/>
```

Comment: What isn't working? Does it not appear? Does it not go back? Does it crash the app?

Comment: Forgot to add in that detail. added!

Answer (score 1):

In TopAppBar, the `NavigationHelper.GoBackCommand` is invalid. You can add Click method to your Button. just like this:

```
<Button ... Click="backBtn_Click"/>
```

in C#：

```
private void backBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Frame.CanGoBack)
        Frame.GoBack();
}
```

Comment: I see... Why is NavigationHelper.GoBackCommand  invalid in TopAppBar?

Comment: I've seen this issue, but I also don't know why.

Comment: What's the datacontext of the TopAppBar?